# Is there any (opposite of newline) char?

Tags: language-agnostic, newline

Was wondering if we could print from right to left, bottom to top... I got this thought when trying to write a program to print the following square (for an input 'n', here n=4 )

```
1  2  3  4
12 13 14 5
11 16 15 6 
10 9  8  7
```

This could be solved many ways, by storing into a 2D array and printing the array... (Any language: Perl, C, C++, Java).

Comment: Is there some reason why you cannot go left to right, top to bottom?  I have code that does column-major printing (you do row-major), which is quite useful.  Think of the normal output of `ls -C`, which is column-major.

Comment: I've heard such a character sequence jokingly called a 'line starve' as the presumed inverse of a line feed.  It's definitely terminal-dependent though.  http://foldoc.org/line+starve

Answer (score 9):

The long answer is that you can do whatever the terminal supports. There are many kinds of terminals (or “character output devices”), many of them support cursor motions. (You can see the  [Termcap Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/termcap.html) project to create a picture what different terminal types do.) There is a terminal command for moving up a line, so esentially yes, you should be able to do that. After poking in the [termcap database](http://www.catb.org/~esr/terminfo/), I came up with the following:

```perl
$ printf "\n"; printf '\e[A'; echo Foo
Foo
```

In other words, the `\e[A` string has a non-zero chance to get you one line up. On some terminals :)

Comment: A quick CNAP search found [Term::Cap](http://search.cpan.org/~jstowe/Term-Cap-1.12/Cap.pm). I have not used it though.

Comment: Ah yes, in my terminal hunt I completely forgot that the solution does not have to be a simple escape string. In that case there are plenty libraries for sure that will do cursor positioning for you.

Comment: "reverse line feed" is `\eM`

Answer (score 1):

Baiscly this is possible. But not on an traditional line-based terminal. When accessing the screen pixel based, it's quite easy to solve this problem. At least there is no real counterpart to \n defined in ASCII.

Or maybe this could be archived by changing the input method of the terminal to some culture which reads left to right and bottom to up.

Answer (score 0):

The Unicode character `0x8d` is defined as a reverse line feed, but it probably doesn’t work in some places.