# how to move up to the previous line in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, console, console-application, windows-console

Is there any character that allows me to move up?

I want to print this:

```
********
*      *
*      *
*      *
*      *
********
```

I just printed this:

[image: done]

how can I complete this figure?

I'm writing a windows console-application.

Comment: Depends on your terminal or other output device/software, maybe.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo it's not answer of the question. thx.

Comment: See things like [Curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) or [Windows Console API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx).  Programs like Vim and Nethack depend on these abilities to know the size of the screen and do arbitrary cursor control.  But note that once you start using such functionality your program loses generality and portability; it will interfere with redirecting output to files/etc.  Sticking to ASCII and Unicode output is best if you can.

Comment: @coni: How and why don't you think your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872976/is-there-any-opposite-of-newline-char? Edit your question with a clarification, and it might be re-opened if people concurr. (At the moment, it looks like a clear-cut dupe.)

Comment: @Deduplicator how many times I must said "I searched some forums (and also stacoverflow) and Google. but I couldn't *achieve* solution." Thus, please stop commenting the same things. Thanks. 
P.S: and also the solution (this one: `stackoverflow.com/questions/4872976/`) is not solves my problem. again and again thanks.

Comment: The trouble is that "It does not help me" does not in any way change the question you actually asked, which is the only question we can answer. Follow my advice and clarify the question by [edit]ing.

Comment: @Deduplicator can u answer my question at this moment ?

Comment: @coni: Well done. Now it is no longer a duplicate as the windows console does not have any move-up-escapes, and you asked for what you want to do, not for a specific way to do it. Upvoted and voted to re-open. (Aside: While the picture is good enough, it would have been better to use text like you did for your wished-for end-result.)

Comment: @Deduplicator: understand. I'll consider it. very thanks. ;) :)

Comment: There are two ways you can go about it: Change what you output, so you only print the final figure like Alf suggests, or look at the [windows console functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx), especially `SetConsoleCursorPosition`.

Comment: hm. I don't know anything about the `vectors`. So I can't use the Alf suggestion. Thus, I must use the win console functions. 
P.S: but I don't know how.
Thanks.

Comment: Now that you have shown us what you are actually trying to achieve, why would you want to move the cursor up a line at all?  Can't you just print those lines one-by-one?  I mean, print `'*'`, then correct number of `' '` then again `'*'` and then `'\n'`.  You'll need a nested loop for this.  Just make your program repeat what you (presumably) did on the keyboard while typing the picture for the desired output.

Comment: Please, can you post the codes as example?

Answer (score 4):

<sup>The question has changed substantially after I posted this answer.</sup>

---

Moving up one line has nothing to do with C++, but with the capabilities of the output device and how it expects such an action to be encoded.

There is no support for it in ASCII, or in the C++ standard library, or (as I recall) e.g. in ANSI escape sequences.

One way to achieve the effect is to generate the output in an internal buffer, e.g. a `vector<string>` in C++, and then output the buffer contents after all the output has been generated.

Comment: Oh, [there is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes) an escape code for that.  It is `\033[1F`.

Comment: @5gon12eder I also read this topic, but it didn't help me. It prints like this: `<-[1F`. Is there any library I should include? I'm using `iostream` and `string`. Thanks.

Comment: @coni You should probably use the “one way” Cheers and hth. - Alf is mentioning.  But if you want a library for terminal control: have a look at (n)curses.  If the escape codes are not working, it has nothing to do with your C++ code but with your terminal (emulator), again as stated in the above answer.

Comment: @5gon12eder: okay. very thanks for attention and commenting :)

Comment: @5gon12eder: Thanks! I didn't know that. Glad I included weasel wording... ;-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf can u answer my question at this moment ? thx.

Comment: @coni: He did. 51 minutes ago.

Comment: But I don't know anything about the `vectors`. also teacher didn't said us about it in lesson. :/

Comment: @coni: For the reworded question, to generate a rectangle of asterisks in the console, just output them in reading/writing order. It's that simple. Tip: to take a screenshot of a single window instead of the whole screen, in Windows use Alt PrtScr.